# How to Handle mobile screen orientation android

Tags: android, screen-orientation

i want to know how to handle mobile screen orientation means in android mobile if i make the mobile horizotal then it's layout also be horizontol and when i turns it to verical then it's layout become vertical..but when i make horizontol then my UI becomes change and unlike to me..

1)  so is there any way so that when i make it horizontol then my UI automatically set according to that heiht and width.
and my

2)  **second qus** is that if i not want to change the orientation when i make it horizontol means if i make mobile horizontol then also its orientation will not change and it remains same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have two layout for both Landscape and Potrait and put your landscapelayout to layout-land and protrailayout to layout folder . Android will  automatically do the rest of the things for you .

if you are in landscape or portrait Android looks for the layout file in either the -port or -land directory first, if it's not found then it falls back to the default layout directory.

you can read it here..http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

Comment: @sujit hi sujit can u explain me in detail bcoz i am new in android and java and i am unable to understood ur hint pls  pls..

Comment: just create one more folder inside your res folder and named it layout-land . Then create your layout for Landscape and put it in that folder.

Comment: and also explain if i not want to change the orientation from vertical to horizontol  in my app then what to do?

Comment: if you want your activity to be fixed for one orientation then you can use this android:screenOrientation="potrait" in your activity tag inside manifest.

Comment: but when i go in next activity its become portrait why???means only my launch page is remains in portrait mode

Comment: If you want to fix portrait for this activity as well then again you have to add the same in manifest for  this activity.

Comment: @sujit sujit if i make from landscape and portrait and vice versa then each time ONCreate() method is called ..is there any way that each time oncreate() method not call and it load as it is....

Comment: yes use this in your activity tag in manifest..android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"

Answer (score 1):

Add this in your Manifest file in your activity for the fixed orientation you want for your Activity

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

like

```
<activity android:name=".Settings" android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
```

Comment: means in every activity i have to set this line??

Comment: try putting it in your application tab.or your will have to put it inside each activity.

Comment: harinder if i make from landscape and portrait and vice versa then each time ONCreate() method is called ..is there any way that each time oncreate() method not call and it load as it is....